# The ten martini problem - reason for name

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology

Why is the problem called the ten martini problem? Sounds like an interesting name for people who drink.

Comment: Here Terry Tao says it is because Kac offered ten martinis for the solution: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/avila-bhargava-hairer-mirzakhani/

Comment: Kac probably got the idea from participating in mathematicians' discussions in the famous Scottish Cafe when he was a student, and then a young researcher in Lwow before 1939. Quite often, a prize for solving a problem was a drink. See e.g. Problem 8 here: http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/ks-szkocka/ks-szkocka3ang.pdf

Comment: @MargaretFriedland --- very interesting!  here's a photograph of the Scottish Book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Book

Comment: @Carlo-- the link I gave is to the  typewritten English translation of the Scottish book. The portal has also complete reproductions of the Polish handwritten original and its typed version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name was coined by Barry Simon in this 1982 [article](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/R26.pdf) (page 487):

> **The Ten Martini Problem:** *The almost Mathieu operator has a Cantor spectrum.*
>
> The name comes from the fact that Mark Kac* has offered ten
>   martinis to anyone who solves it.  [...] Actually, Kac said "has all
>   its gaps there", so perhaps one should solve instead:
>
> **The Ten Martini Problem:** (Strong Form, or should it be Dry Form)...
>
> [*] Marc Kac, public communication at 1981 AMS Annual Meeting.